# Looking for something similar to "Views selective filters", just with "inactive" instead of "removed"

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

The [Views Selective Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) module reduces the filter items in a views exposed filter to only those having actually results.

I'm searching something similar, but I don't want to hide the options with no results, instead I want to make them inactive (shown greyed out).

The exposed filter list I have is just a vocabulary with some category terms.

Is there a module for this somewhere out there? Or how can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to gray out items in a combobox? If using Better Exposed filters module to replace the combox with some other widget, you can easily use Views Selective Filters and some Javascript to do the magic.

Answer (score 0):

## Views Dependent Filters

Consider looking at the [Views Dependent Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dependent_filters) module, which might help. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Allows the presence of exposed filters on a view to be controlled by values in another exposed filter. Dependent filters are hidden when not relevant, and their values are not considered when the exposed form is submitted.
>
> The module is compatible with both the Views basic and the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) form plugins.

Investigate how the technique of "filters are hidden when not relevant" is implemented and try to someho tweek that if needed to perfectly meet your needs.

Its [readme.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/views_dependent_filters/tree/README.txt?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-1.x) file contains some more information about this module.

## Views Reference Filter

Another module that might help is the [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) module. From its project page:

> Imagine you have taxonomy terms in exposed filter widget (drop down select list). But for some reason you want to show just several terms, not all the dictionary. With this module, you can do this by creating a separate view which generates the desired list of terms.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have two filters for the field, one selective and one normal.

I'd hide the normal one with css and use jQuery to loop through it, compare the entries to the selective list, and add any extras + a class to disable them.